# Inherited auto-implemented property with private setter

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, access-modifiers

I have a base class and a derived class.  Each has the same property which has a `private` setter so the value can be set by some logic inside the class.

```
class First
{
    internal virtual int Value { get; private set; }

    void SetValue(int toValue)
    {
        Value = toValue;
    }
}

class Second : First
{
    internal override int Value { get; private set; }

    void SetValue(int toValue)
    {
        Value = toValue;
    }
}
```

This is resulting in a compiler error:

> The property or indexer ... cannot be used in this context because the
>   set accessor is inaccessible.

Why is that the case, and how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?  Is this not possible with auto-implemented properties, in other words, do I have to use a backing field instead?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Having independent properties with the same name sounds like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: That's the whole point behind virtual members: being able to override them in a derived class with a more concrete logic.  I'm not sure I follow your reasoning.

Comment: But you don't have concrete logic - you just have another auto-implemented property. And if you think about the property as a public get and a private set, it makes perfect sense that you can't override the private method. Again, what are you really trying to achieve? Can you give a more meaningful example?

Answer (score 2):

`Second` would be unable to `set` the value of `Value` from `First` due to `Value`s setter being `private`.  If you need your subclass to be able to set it, it needs to be `protected` in the base.

Comment: I bet I've looked at 20 or so Q&A about this...the protected access modifies seem to be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Getters and Setters are basically methods. You can't override methods you can't see. The `virtual` in this case only applies to the getter as `virtual private` is not allowable.

It's not just that you can't see it to use it, you cannot override it at all.